# How to delete/remove a section and it's rows in UITableView on demand in IOS APP using swift2+

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to delete a section and it's rows in UITableView when user clicks on delete icon shown in section.

One solution i know, is delete object from array and reload the table, but this is not a process effective solution.

Comment: Look at the docs for `UITableView`. There are methods for inserting, deleting, and reloading rows and sections.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the section with the built in tableView method after deleting the data from the datasource.

```
datasource.deleteSection()
tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

Comment: My datasource is set as `table.dataSource = self`.  I don't know how to perform `datasource.deleteSection() ` in my case.

Comment: @PlateReverb not the `tableViews` datasource, the actual datasource that is supplying the table with data. So if you have an array of names that is displayed in your `tableView`, delete the name in your array first, then the row in your `tableView` second, or in this example, section.

Comment: hmm... my sections are not populated by arrays, but rather by literals... I feel like I'm probably missing something and need to write my own question...

Comment: @PlateReverb sounds like it :) you can pm me if you need further help also

Comment: I still don't know how to solve it the way you described, but I solved the problem by creating an array and ONLY applying `array.removeAll()`, `sectionTitles[4] = ""` and `table.reloadData()`.  I'd like to learn how to do it the above way some other time, but your comment helped me figure this out.  I might take you up on your pm offer if I do need help.  Thanks!